# vs2017 margin colors for altered lines?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

VS2015 has margin colors for altered lines, but where is it in VS2017? I really liked that feature.

VS2015 color scheme:

```
No color = Line unchanged since you opened the file

Green = Line changed since you opened the file, but saved

Yellow = Line changed since you last saved
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is located (somewhat counter-intuitively) in the per-language Text Editor options. Although this allows for differing options in different languages.
[Text Editor >> C/C++ >> Scroll Bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUrfa.png)